# How to change Firefox search box popup font size?

Tags: firefox, gui, css

How to change Firefox search box popup font size using `userChrome.css`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
.autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-title {
  font-size: 13px !important;
   padding:3px 0px !important;
}
```

Or complete userChrome.css:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); 

#main-menubar{
  padding-top:6px !important
}

#urlbar,
#searchbar .searchbar-textbox,
#searchbar .searchbar-textbox:hover,
#searchbar .searchbar-textbox[focused="true"],
#searchbar .searchbar-textbox[focused="true"]:hover {
  box-shadow: initial !important;
  border-color: #B9B9BA !important
}

#urlbar .urlbar-input-box,
#searchbar .searchbar-textbox {
  font-size: 11px !important
}


.autocomplete-richlistitem .ac-title {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  padding: 2px 0px !important
}
```

[image]